# Site collection vs central admin search managed properties

Tags: managed-property, crawled-property

http://sales.inside.nov/_layouts/15/listmanagedproperties.aspx?level=site 
I see a **Managed property** "ReportType" at the site collection level and this is mapped to `ows_ReportType`.

However, when I go to **Search service application > search schema**, i see following

> owstaxIdReportType and it's mapped to ows_taxId_ReportType crawled property.

Can **crawled properties** be different at the site level vs SSA (search svc app)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A good article that explains some differences :
http://prashamsabadra.blogspot.de/2013/08/difference-between-managed-property.html

Hope this will help.

Comment: The article helps. Here is another one https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/03/02/creating-refinable-and-sortable-managed-properties-in-sites-and-site-collections-in-sharepoint-2013. I deleted the property at the site collection and added a SSA level. Thanks. Btw, I did not post that comment.

Comment: @KevinShort I know it was not you :). The reply  was from the moderators.